# smooth scroll to top not working smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to make the scrolling to top smooth, but the code i was provided doesnt seem to work. the scrolling just wont be smooth...

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var $target = $(this.hash);
      $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if ($target.length) {
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: targetOffset
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a name="top" id="top"></a>
<div style="height:2000px">
  a hell lot of content here
</div>
<a href="#top">back to top</a>
```

why isnt it working?

Comment: What's up with all the `&amp;amp;`?

Comment: it was in the code i copied. deleted them but still doesnt work

Comment: `&amp;` in HTML means `&`. That means you don't want to remove them; you want to replace them with `&`s.

Comment: &amp; is an & yeah, but whats the amp; after it?

Comment: @caro it's been escaped twice. If you have `&` it escapes to `&amp;`. If you escape that you get `&amp;amp;`

Comment: even with the &'s in it, it refuses to work ;(

Comment: I moved the code into a snippet and made the body large enough to be scrollable. Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 maybe copying codes and learning from them is a start to understand the working methods. i wasnt born with perfect knowledge of everything like you obviously are -.-

Comment: @Caro No, copying codes does not help you in learning. Never in any course or quality tutorials would have told you to copy codes. In my opinion understanding the different parts of the language and environment and try to put them together to create something new is the best way to learn (that's there are "coding playgrounds".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `||` instead of `&amp;amp;&amp;amp;` and some minor changes
Corrected:

```js
$(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top">Some things here</div> .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here ..<a href="#top">TOP</a>
```

Here [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mostafas/egq8au22/2/)